# How can I make remote clients get access to my server?

Tags: socket.io, server, ip, netty

there, 
I am trying to write a chatting application with netty-socket io https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio.

my code for server

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setHostname(my IP address);  
    config.setPort(3000);
    final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
    server.start();
```

on the client(web page) I have:

```
    var socket =  io.connect(my IP address);
```

when I user my public/ external IP address (the one you get when you google "what is my ip"), I got **Cannot assign requested address: bind** error

when I use my internal address, the server can only be accessed by the clients on the same network (my school's wifi)

I just want to know how remote clients can access to the server on my machines through ip address. Thank you.

I am quite new to this area and have lots of doubts, so if the question is stupid, sorry in advance.

Comment: This is a firewall and / or routing issue

Comment: so which ip address should I use? external ip or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't be accessed by external client when you use your public IP because it is the public IP of your school (all connected machines have the same shared public/external IP) and the firewall or router of your school is not configured to route trafic from port 3000 to your specific machine.
The configuration must be changed... but probably you can't do that.

So, you can bind only a ip/port with your internal network IP and be accessed only by machines on same network.

The best solution is probably to put your server outside the school's network, by using a hosting service

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any recommendation on the hosting service ??

Comment: @Kevin Not really, you have many many providers (like gandi, ovh, google, amazon, ...) choose the one you prefer. You can also use your own machine, it's maybe a litle less expensive but it must be outside of your school's network and constantly online to be accessed.